# Pressure in Fluids,in particular horizontal pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I am not sure about the pressure existing in fluids.If the vertical pressure acts due to gravity and the atmospheric pressure since it also changes due to height also acts due to gravity then why is there horizontal pressure in a liquid. If there is then is it also equal to the vertical pressure at the point?

If gravity is suddenly stopped then do we still have water pressure and atmospheric pressure? In air is pressure equal in all directions? An interesting theory one of my friends explained is that if there is a box of air in space with no gravity and they have a velocity in one direction and due to elastic collisions there is pressure in all directions. But is it so that pressure in liquids act only due to moving molecules colliding randomly if there is no gravity?

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The up-down pressure from gravity/air meets the down-up resistance of container's bottom (and fluids are hardly compressible). This makes particles "look for their way out of the trap". The only option (if possible) is go sideways.

(If you exert additional pressure on the block of butter with the palm of you hand, it will get squeezed out sideways.)

Without gravity there is obviously no atmospheric pressure as well. It is gravity that retains air at the Earth's surface, so atmospheric pressure is the result of air's weight. Without gravity the atmosphere would have escaped into space.

Simple velocity (without acceleration) of a box in space changes nothing. Constant velocity means no force acting on the fluid inside the box (Newton's first law), so the fluid will exert equal pressure on all the walls of the box. (Gravity-generated pressure results from acceleration and not from gravity.)

EDIT: Gas or liquid is not held together like a solid body is. Their intermolecular attractions are weak compared to the kinetic energy of their molecules. These molecules propelled by their kinetic energy exert uniform pressure on all of the walls of the container it is held in (fluid would not normally exert pressure on the top wall of the container) as its molecules move around chaotically. If there is no gravity present, the value of this pressure depends on its kinetic energy, which varies with the temperature (compression is also a factor here).

Now, gravity is acceleration ($g=9,81 m/s^2$) and that's why it pulls air in the direction of the gravity source. If a gas would be held in a container placed in space without gravity, the pressure of the molecules would exert equal pressure on all the walls (that's the case I described in the paragraph above). Adding simple constant velocity would not change that (Newton: "When viewed in an inertial reference frame [i.e. at rest or with constant velocity], an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by an external force [which is the source of acceleration].")

Going back to your first question to sum up. **Horizontal pressure in liquid results from two factors - the kinetic energy of molecules (which makes them move chaotically in all directions) and the Earth's gravity (as molecules are pulled down by gravity and look for escape sideways)**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.Could you please explain the last paragraph in a little more detail?And also without gravity there is no air pressure?Won't air molecules still be moving around?

Comment: So if at a particular height the absolute pressure was P then if you place a sheet in the water what is the magnitude of horizontal force on the two sides of the sheet?

Comment: This is actually a new question. You should simply ask it in a separate thread, I think.

Comment: NOTICE, you received a down-vote from somebody for your question. It wasn't me, and I can only guess that this person thought you hadn't explored the subject on your own before asking. I suggest you take a look in Wikipedia or other internet sources for atmospheric pressure, states of matter, etc. And if you still can't understand something, then ask specific questions. This place is not considered an alternative to Wikipedia, but rather a way of assistance if regular sources are not clear enough to you (if you believe I answered your initial question then mark it as answered)

Comment: See my summary above.

Comment: I do not intend it to be an alternative to wikipedia.And the questions are very much relevant to each other and that was the reason I posted it in the same place.I wanted to see if I can imply the second question from the first.I have a general understanding about pressure and their change with height but what I don't get is why there must be horizontal pressure at all and if so the magnitude of it and if it varies the same way as vertical pressure.Everywhere else it is assumed that at a point the pressure by fluid in horizontal is equal to vertical.0

Comment: @user45388: "Everywhere else it is assumed that at a point the pressure by fluid in horizontal is equal to vertical." And that is true (provided a point can actually exert pressure in both directions), as long as you neglect gravity and consider an ideal case. Therefore, if you want to understand the behaviour of gases or liquids "in themselves", you assume the pressure is the same in all directions. *On top of that* you can add gravity to consider their behavior in real-life situations.

Comment: Why oh why is there horizontal pressure on the walls of the container and why is it equal to the vertical pressure at that point?

Comment: Is it only the horizontal pressure that bothers you? Or, saying it differently, why do you think there shouldn't be any pressure in the horizontal direction? Why should it be special? If you blow a balloon it will grow in all directions, because kinetic energy of molecules moves them in all directions, haphazardly. If you fill it with water in non-gravity conditions it will also grow in all directions (in a gravitational field it will grow in all directions too, but the direction of the gravity will by grossly dominated).

Comment: Molecules in liquid are not static -  that's why sugar in you coffee will dissolve even without stirring if you wait long enough. And movement means pressure.

Comment: I mean generally pressure on a horizontal 2D plate on it's top is due to atmospheric pressure on the top due to gravity but if the same plate is tilted 90 degrees then on the same side why must there be any pressure since there is no gravity and even if there is pressure how could it be equal to the first pressure in the initial horizontal situation

Comment: It's like asking why does a piece of metal will get flattened out, if hit from above with a hammer? Gravity is like this hammer, only weaker. If you have a certain amount of molecules (atoms) in a vertical direction and you squeeze them strong enough, they will be displaced sideways, because the force that binds them is stronger and each atom is unsqueezable. Therefore the vertical pressure will get converted horizontally. Make a box with a thin paper, fill it with little balls and press it from above. Balls will go sideways, as they are not placed ideally ....

Comment: cd. ... one on top of another, so they are not pushed ideally in vertical direction. Take snooker - if you hit a ball ideally in the center it will go straight up. But if you miss the very center, it will go sideways. That's how force coming from one direction gets redirected. Consider molecules and atoms such balls.

Comment: Or put a very tiny drop of water on a table. If it's really small, it will hold together. But it can be only this big to remain "in one piece". Add gently another drop to it (or simply make another one but significantly bigger) and it will fall apart. Why? Because it's mass will increase, and therefore the force exerted by the gravity will also increase ($F=ma$), while the binding force between molecules will remain the same and become relatively too weak to resist. As a result, the water drop will fall apart *horizontally*, because that's how the direction of force will be converted.

Comment: Is it really equal?How can you justify conversion of vertical force to horizontal force?It's alright that the balls go to the right when squashed but is it really (density*g*h)?

Comment: I never measured it. (I don't think I can add anything else meaningful to explain. I tried my best. If what I said is not enough for you, then you should wait for somebody else to answer it better.)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to try to answer.I don't think I phrased the question properly in the beginning.Ah well let's see

Comment: @brightmagus .....Superb Answer....Only 1 thing which I couldn't get is ( let's just talk about water in a tank in gravity , because air and water both are fluids and you yourself mentioned in the last paragraph that the total hydrostatic pressure in the liquid is the sum of the pressures due to kinetic energy of the molecules and due to gravity. So why does the formula which we use P = hpg for finding the pressure does not account for the pressure due the K.E of the molecules ? Your explanation seems to be exactly correct. Gas has pressure due to the velocity of molecules.

Comment: @brightmagus  Why then we not include the pressure due to kinetic energy and velocities of the molecules in finding the TOTAL absolute pressure in the equation P=hpg

Comment: @Shashaank: because these velocities - being completely random - average to zero.

Comment: @brightmagus  Do you mean  that since the velocities are completely random , the net  force generated by these moving molecules ( net force i.e the sum in all directions ) becomes 0 ? If that's the case why in the case of a gas we take out this pressure P=1/3pv^2 ? Why not just do with the gravity generated pressure in the gas ?

Comment: @Shashaank, I think you should post a new question (perhaps with a reference to this one), where you can present your doubts at length, and where you can receive clear and satisfying questions. It's difficult to do it here.

Comment: @brightmagus Ok I will post a new question , but I am afraid it will be down voted. I will try to present my doubts at length and give reference to this question. It would be good if you can answer the question there since you know the entire development of the question and since it is based on your answer.